# Didn't get notifications for Custodian badge

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, stack-overflow, notifications

I didn't get the badge notification for the *Custodian* badge:

[image]

I don't mind not getting notified for a *Suggested Edit* I accepted months ago. But my *First Post* reviewed badge was awarded because of a review I just did few minutes ago and I was totally expecting to get notified.

Is this supposed to happen?

**Note:** people *are* [being notified](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147922/179635) about this badge in StackOverflow

Comment: I didn't get any notification for my "Custodian" badges either (but got notifications for "Reviewer" and "Steward"). Could be that too many get them to send out all the notifications immediately.

Comment: I didn't get any notification for the Custodian badge either. I guess reputation comes into play.

Comment: I just got notified on both meta and SO... not sure whether I deserve them or not but badges are always good.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This was also [asked on Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4062/32), I'll copy my answer here for reference:

> Most of the bronze badges don't notify users who are considered
>   "veterans" of the network, which is (loosely) defined as having
>   accounts on multiple non-meta sites.
>
> The rationale is that getting a notification every time you join a new
>   site and, say, downvote gets a tad annoying after a while.
>
> Custodian, being one of the "you did one thing"-bronze badges is one
>   of those who's notifications are suppressed.