# Small typo in the notification for New Community Review badges

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications, wording

I just earned the new "Custodian","Reviewer" and "Steward"  badge and I noticed that the message has the word "for" twice in a row.  Should the alert be modified so that it is more grammatically correct?

[image]

Similarly for other review badges:

[image]

Comment: It should be "eight" really if you're working the sums

Comment: The same message is for "Reviewer" & "Steward" badge, i just notice.

Answer (score 5):

"It should be eight really" - I LOLed.  Thanks for the report, a fix is rolling out.