# Why don't I get notification for review badges?

Tags: bug, badges, notifications

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Didn’t get notifications for Custodian badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147918/didnt-get-notifications-for-custodian-badge)

I earned 6x Custodian badges but didn't receive a notification for any. Is this a bug or by design?

Comment: Bronze badges don't generate notifications for users that are considered "veterans"...

Comment: @YannisRizos "Veterans"? What's the criteria for that? My rep is 5462 at the time of this writing.

Comment: @YannisRizos Only *some* bronze badges don't generate notifications. Some of them (such as "Nice Answer") always generate a notification.

Comment: @Flem That's a good Meta question ;) I have no idea what the exact criteria is, and what badges are affected.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Copying [Kevin Montrose's answer](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4062/25936) on a [similar question](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/no-notification-for-custodian-badge) on Meta Programmers:

> Most of the bronze badges don't notify users who are considered "veterans" of the network, which is (loosely) defined as having accounts on multiple non-meta sites.
>
> The rationale is that getting a notification everytime you join a new site and, say, downvote gets a tad annoying after a while.
>
> Custodian, being one of the "you did one thing"-bronze badges is one of those who's notifications are suppressed.

While I don't know what the exact criteria is, I'm certainly glad [Geoff manually set IsVeteran](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4040/no-notification-for-custodian-badge#comment11616_4062) on my account and I no longer get notifications for every silly bronze badge.