# Why would the badge count up by my rep be too high?

Tags: support, badges

I found some other questions about badge count but they all were either

- status completed
- or referred to cached counts being too low for a while

Yesterday I had 4 gold meta badges. Thanks to the tireless efforts of gnat, I knew I was close to Great Question. This morning sure enough, I have it. But the top summary says 6 gold.

[image]

To answer possible objections:

- there is not a sixth badge a little further down if I just scrolled
- I did not get any of those twice
- I am pretty sure Great Question doesn't count for 2 badges :-)

How can the counts get out of sync like this - and especially how can the summary end up too high?

Answer (score 10):

You have 2 reversal badges. The `Badges` tab only shows checkmarks next to earned badges, not a count, even if you earned more than one.

Take a look at your own [badges tab, sorted by class](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147247/kate-gregory?tab=badges&sort=class):

[image: gold badge counts]

Looks like you had *5* gold badges yesterday and didn't even know you did. :-)

You can see exactly when you received badges on your [activity tab, filterable by badges only](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147247/kate-gregory?tab=activity&sort=badges). As you can see, you have had 5 badges since 2012-10-24. You probably got confused with your Stack Overflow account, where you have had [4 gold badges since 2012-10-11](https://stackoverflow.com/users/203458/kate-gregory?tab=activity&sort=badges).

Comment: Easy meta rep! ☺

Comment: Oh my! You're right. 5 or 6 days ago apparently. But I was never notified (I just looked through the notifications to confirm) and my badge count was totally 4 last night. So this turn out to be that the count was too low and then fixed itself when another badge was awwarded.

Comment: @Kate As veteran user you don't get notification for every badge.

Comment: @KateGregory: You have 4 gold badges on Stack Overflow, are you sure you didn't get confused between sites?

Comment: @KateGregory: Check your [activity tab, filtered on badges](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/147247/kate-gregory?tab=activity&sort=badges) to check when you got your 5th badge. Answer: October 24th. On [Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/users/203458/kate-gregory?tab=activity&sort=badges) you got a 4th gold badge on October 11th.

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd surely no-one is so veteran that another gold badge is ho hum no big deal, stop notifying me of this trivia? Even Jon Skeet?

Comment: @ShaWizDowArd: That does *not* apply to gold badges, [only bronze badges are silenced](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147918/didnt-get-notifications-for-custodian-badge) when you are a veteran (== member of multiple SE sites).

Comment: @Kate indeed, Martijn is correct. Something else is going on then.